# Насколько увеличивается расход вычислительных ресурсов при обкладывании полей свойствами с C#?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, производительность

Свойства с C# могут быть чрезвычайно полезными во многих ситуациях, но какова плата производительностью за их использование?

Логики в геттерах и сеттерах в принципе может быть сколько угодно много, но возьмём минимальных случай - по геттеру и сеттеру для каждого поля, которые не делают ничего, кроме выдачи и установки значения соответственно.

Итак, насколько инстансы класса

```cs
public class Person
{

  public required uint ID { get; init; }

  public required string Name { get; set; }
  
  public required string Email { get; set; }

  public required string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

  public byte? Age { get; set; }

  // И ещё штук 100-200, если это реальное коммерческое приложение

}
```

будут тормозить приложение больше, чем нижеследующая реализация?

```cs
public class Person
{

  public required uint ID;

  public required string Name;
  
  public required string Email;

  public required string PhoneNumber;

  public byte? Age;

  // И ещё штук 100-200, если это реальное коммерческое приложение

}
```

Естественно, что дать ответ в миллисекундах я Вас не прошу, достаточно одной из следующих качественных оценок:

- Влияние пренебрежимо мало даже для крупных коммерческих и государственных приложений, работающих с большими объёмами данных
- Влияние пренебрежимо мало в средних приложениях, но начинает ощущаться в крупных коммерческих и государственных приложениях, работающих с большими объёмами данных
- Влияние пренебрежимо мало в маленьких приложения, но начинает чувствоваться в средних приложениях

Ну, я не думаю что это сколько-то ощутимо в маленьких приложениях, поэтому данного варианта не предлагаю.

Comment: Ну возьми и замерь. Теоретически jit должен разобраться и вообще не должно влиять.

Comment: как много тут всяких заблуждений........ как минимум "*И ещё штук 100-200, если это реальное коммерческое приложение*" - в адекватных нормальных приложениях не будет в одном классе столько полей или свойств, это профессионально и явная 100000% ошибка архитектуры и явное нарушение всяких принципов, как SOLID и пр........... во-вторых не ясно вообще как вы связали объёмы данных, оперируемые в High Load и работа со свойствами...... как это стыкуется одно с другим - не ясно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Благодарю Вас за комментарий. "это профессионально и явная 100000% ошибка архитектуры и явное нарушение всяких принципов, как SOLID и пр" - для среднестатистического класса - да. Но думаю если это сущность "Резидент" в государственном приложении или "Автомобиль" в компании по продаже автомобилей с проектом, то даже с дочерними классами (например, "производитель" или "двигатель" для автомобиля лучше вынести в отдельные классы) полей будет ну несколько десятков - это минимум.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "во-вторых не ясно вообще как вы связали объёмы данных, оперируемые в High Load и работа со свойствами...... как это стыкуется одно с другим - не ясно" - означает ли это, что влияния на производительность пренебрежимо мало?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня были случаи, когда более 100 полей выводилось колонками в таблицу пользователю. Так что вовсе не обязательно это проблемы с архитектурой - может быть реально столько надо.

Comment: @БоковГлеб "*ну несколько десятков - это минимум*" --- во-первых это лишь ваши домыслы. во-вторых - вы показали в примере 200 полей в одном классе, а не общее со всех классов. Если имелось в виду именно общее количество по приложению - так и напишите. В-третьих - это всё одновременно использоваться в любом случае не будет и не должно. Выборка идёт же с конкретными данными, а не сразу со всем)

Comment: У шарпистов и джавистов есть универсальный ответ: "база тормозит". Имеется в виду, что запросы в базу данных занимают большую часть времени. А также чтение файлов с диска, пересылка по сети и т. п.

Comment: @Qwertiy вывести - это одно (и то 100 - это что-то невнятное) , а для вывода вообще это просто как там, POJO (это определение из JAVA но смысл тот же) ? там даже свойств не нужно и тем более какой-то логики, только публичные поля....

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  не только шарпистов... самый затык всегда это операции ввода вывода....и БД))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, дата-объект с сотней полей/свойств без логики. Отправляется массив из нескольких десятков тысяч таких объектов на фронт, там отображается пользователю в виде таблицы со всякими фильтрами и сортировками (интерактивно).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так в шарпе принято всё равно свойства использовать, а не поля. Плюс, ORM и другие штуки с рефлексией поля не любят и часто с ними не работают вообще.

Comment: Вообще на текущий вопрос ответить объективно нельзя. Во-первых даже как написал ТС "реальное коммерческое приложение" может быть разное и использовать разные подходы, архитектуру, структуру, вспомогательные инструменты, может быть даже разработанные внутри компании. Приложение может быть рассчитано на 10тыс человек а может на 100тыс - при этом 10тыс используют как огромную динамически документативную, а 100тыс как редкие справочники... Также зависит от криворукости разработчиков. Одно и то же приложение под действием разных разрабов может работать по-разному от скилов и знаний. А ещё железо

Comment: @Qwertiy поля ведь это то, что с маленькой буквы, а свойства - с большой, правильно?)) Меня шарп путает

Comment: "*Ну, я не думаю что это сколько-то ощутимо в маленьких приложениях, поэтому данного варианта не предлагаю.*" --- не является правдой. как я описал выше. факторов много. Особенно разработчиковский. Плохой код можно написать везде и всегда.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Поля - это "обычные" переменные класса, а свойства - это то, что с `get/set`, регистром букв они не отличаются )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, свойства пишут с большой буквы (это которые get/set), а вот насчёт полей - вроде есть варианты с маленькой и с подчёркивания (приватные), хотя не совсем уверен, есть ли именно приватные поля в стандартном стайл гайде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот как раз здесь проще сделать бенчмарк, чем погружаться в споры об идеологической правильности.
https://pastebin.com/pnTvuxFV (использовалась кодогенерация, исходник достаточно большой, поэтому не привожу его здесь),
результат:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AccessClassWithFields | 406.6 ns | 2.275 ns | 1.900 ns |
| AccessClassWithProps | 2,951.5 ns | 58.379 ns | 102.245 ns |

Результаты вполне объяснимы - при обращении к свойствам на уровне `IL` производится `callvirt` метода-геттера или сеттера, что в любом случае дороже прямого обращения к полю.
А дальше обычно действуют по обстоятельствам.

Comment: Самое главное в табличке то и не написали - а сколько было полей и сколько запросов? Просто если это на миллиард запросов, то и пофик, а если нет? Это же не на одно обращение столько времени?

Comment: Там не было запросов - по ссылке выше на pastebin весь исходник бенчмарка. Просто большая сгенерированная простыня: создаем класс, заполняем поля/свойства, читаем их, возвращаем результат. В каждом классе 676 полей/свойств (в имени 2 символа от A до Z).

Comment: Нет, разумеется, эти цифры - не на одно обращение. Там использовался BenchmarkDotNet - https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet . Он достаточно сложно устроен внутри, и не просто гоняет кусок кода энное количество раз, и сравнивает результаты - там есть и прогревочные запуски, и оценивающие запуски. Если кому-то интересно, могу к этому бенчмарку присоединить полный лог тестирования.

Comment: @CrazyElf, это должно быть в пересчёте на 1 тест - судя по коду это: 1 создание объекта, 1 запись всех полей, 1 чтение всех полей.

Comment: @Qwertiy А, ну это фактически 2 микросекунды, ну нормально для одной операции по всем полям. Я просто что-то никак единицы измерения не мог осознать.

Comment: @user11354240 А, ну я понял. Но лучше всё-таки всю такую инфу где-нибудь рядом с таблицей писать, возможно, с помощью ещё одной таблицы - сколько полей, сколько прогонов и т.д. Если есть такая инфа )

Comment: Есть много всякой инфы. Полный лог бенчмарка выглядит так: https://pastebin.com/eTFsR6SV

Comment: Возможно, операция сложения как то влияет, так как стоило мне убрать сложение из примера ([ссылка на пасту](https://pastebin.com/RKQECuJJ)) как результаты стали [такие](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH3z1.png)

Comment: Я было подумал, окей, я же только пишу в свойства, но не читаю. Сделал [пасту с записью и чтением](https://pastebin.com/Hfzpkd8G), но без суммирования, получил [вот это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9pL7.png)

Comment: ок, я подумал, ну может быть оптимизатор что то мутит, дай ка чуть переделаю, чтобы и поля писать и из методов объект вернуть, а то вдруг оптимизатор решил просто вырезать ненужное, получилась [паста такая](https://pastebin.com/d2Apxnnp), [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0z3l.png) показывает разницу, но не такую драматичную, как у вас. Как вывод я бы сделал - разница есть (очевидно из зи callvirt), но конкретно считать её надо на конкретнном примере. Сказать, что свойства работают в 7 раз медленей полей конечно нельзя.

Comment: Отличную Вы проделали работу. Большая Вам благодарность, зачтение ответа и лайк.

Answer (score 2):

Использование интерфейсов, классов, свойств, функций, паттернов, всяких итераторов, DI контейнеров всегда добавляет какой то оверхед. Большинство подобных вещей существуют не для производительности, а для для других вещей, таких как сложность, скорость разработки, поддержки, модульность, гибкость и прочие вещи. Другими словами, для удобства разработки ПО, а не его скорости работы. Почему это важно? Потому что как только начинаются ужесточения требований к производительности, почти сразу усложняются все остальные вещи, увеличивается время разработки, требуются соотвествующе кадры для подобного. Другими словами, чем жестче требования к производительности, тем дороже выходит разработка такой системы.

Потому, всесто того, чтобы тратить время и деньги на оптимизацию, производимое ПО держат на уровне "достаточном" для того, чтобы им пользоваться, а время и деньги тратятся на развитие, новые фичи и так далее. В итоге ПО "достаточно" быстрое для использования и с необходимым набором фишек - выигрывают все.

Поэтому в общем случае, если у вас выбор между микрооптимизациями и простотой кода/поддержки, по умолчанию выбирайте простоту. Я бы не советовал никому менять свой стиль программирования или отступать от общепринятого без наличия веской приччины, ведь то, что вы нагородите, надо будет годами поддерживать и вероятно не вам.

Подобные оптимизации типа использования полей вместо свойств, могут быть полезны только в самых критически важных для производительности местах, когда структурные и алгоритмические приемы исчерпаны. Я знаю команду, которая по причине производительности, практически не использует классы как таковые и очень редко когда может использовать структуры данных, отличные от массивов - все это по причине критической важности производительности, но это не касается 99.9999% проектов, поверье, если вы попадете в проект с критическими требованиями по производительсности, дилемма поля vs свойства будет наименьшей вашей головной болью.

Что же касается крупных коммерческих приложений, я работал над такими и имел множество полей, и я вам скажу, что нет никакой абсолютно разницы конечному юзеру, откроется у вас форма на 10-100-1000 миллисекунд раньше или нет, зато код у вас будет более поддерживаемым без лишних выкрутасов и бесполезных оптимизаций.

Если вам действительно интересно узнать способы ускорения приложений, то я бы советовал сначала обратить внимание на тему алгоритмов, на всякие возможности тестирования производительности, поиска "бутылочного горлышка", так как абсолютное большинство тормозов происходят из за работы с вводом/выводом (сеть, БД, файлы) или линейным поиском в списке вместо константного в хештаблице/хешсете (я сбился со счета сколько раз я подобное правил).

Если вам интересен мой опыт оптимизации программ, в этом году я рассказывал о нем в [интервью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/655927/). (не сочтите за рекламу, мне оттуда уже никакого профита)

Comment: Очень признателен Вам за Ваши замечательные ответы на вопросы - и на этот, и на мои предыдущие. ...Даже не знаю, почему Вы, явно высокооплачиваемый специалист, инвестируете в меня Ваше бесценное время, при том что очень рад этому. В ответ на вопрос Вы включили знания, полученные в результате прохождения огня и воды, реальных коммерческих проектов, и стоят эти знания побольше, чем просто "спасибо"...

Answer (score 2):

Согласен, в самом первом бенчмарке много лишнего шума - создание экземпляра класса, сложение. Его можно сильно упростить, и выполнить энное количество раз (проход по энумератору Repeat будет учтен в результатах для каждого варианта):

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
  }

  ClassWithProps _classWithProps;
  СlassWithFields _classWithFields;
  [GlobalSetup]
  public void GlobalSetup()
  {
    _classWithProps = new ClassWithProps();
    _classWithFields = new СlassWithFields();
  }

  [Benchmark]
  public bool AccessClassWithFields()
  {
    foreach(var n in Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000))
    {
      _classWithFields.A = 1;
      int x = _classWithFields.A;
    }
    return true;
  }

  [Benchmark]
  public bool AccessClassWithProps()
  {
    foreach(var n in Enumerable.Repeat(1, 100000))
    {
      _classWithProps.A = 1;
      int x = _classWithProps.A;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public class ClassWithProps
  {
    public int A { get; set; }
  }

  public class СlassWithFields
  {
    public int A;
  }
}
```

(я проверил, оптимизатор не выкинул ничего существенного). Разница в результатах получается ещё меньше: значение `Mean` у `AccessClassWithProps` равно `400.7`, у `AccessClassWithFields` равно `345.2`.

Comment: Ну вот это похоже на правду. А если в реальном сценарии, когда ещё какая-то логика будет, а не только инициализация полей, то скорее всего разница вообще будет незаметна.

Comment: Ценность на этом сайте несут вопросы и ответы, но не комментарии. Потому я бы вам советовал обновить ваш ответ с галкой, а не создавать новый, ведь если кто то будет искать ответ на подобный вопрос, он прочитает ответ с галкой и  проигнорирует все остальное, а там хоть и выводы вцелом верные, но разница сильно большая.